# Ansible: how-to do math and get an integer?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

If we assume that `ansible_memtotal_mb` is an odd number

```
- debug: msg="{{ ansible_memtotal_mb }}"
```

How can I divide `ansible_memtotal_mb` by 2, and convert the result to an integer:

```
- debug: msg="{{ ansible_memtotal_mb * 0.5 | int }}"
```

Obviously the latter did not work, because (if I am not mistaken)
`ansible_memtotal_mb * 0.5` returns a string and using the `int` filter, results to `0`

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You applied `int` filter to the value `0.5`.

You wanted to apply to the result of the expression, so:

```
- debug: msg="{{ (ansible_memtotal_mb * 0.5) | int }}"
```

Comment: aaah - got it in the second visit: the pipe operator has higher priority than the multiplication sign.

Comment: there is a simpler way - just divide ansible_memtotal by two "{{ ansible_memtotal_mb / 2 }}"

Comment: @DmitryLihachev this would trigger a floating point division, which would not necessarily yield the expected result. However, `{{ ansible_memtotal_mb // 2 }}` (with two slashes) performs an integer division and is indeed a simpler solution.